# SonicWall Configuration

Tags: networking, configuration, firewall, administration, sonicwall

My company is looking for a tool or idea on how we can manage the configurations on our firewalls. We would like to be able to export a file of a "good" firewall configuration and be able to compare it to our other firewalls. We are trying to see differences between offices and even changes over time.

We have used the tool "Autodoc" to be able to export our configuration files but aren't able to compare it with others easily. Using this, we would have to manually go line for line to see any differences.

Maybe even something with Command Line?

Is there anything out there that is able to do this?

Any information or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the CLI you can export the configuration as a text file. I think the command is:

```
export current-config cli
```

Once you have that file any File comparison tool can help you to spot the differences

You can see a further information in this KB. 
https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/export-configuration-settings-using-enterprise-command-line-interface-e-cli/170504991622695/

Comment: Thanks for the response. We have done it this way before. We are looking to see if there is an all in one tool that could do this.

Comment: Although it sounds like a useful tool. I don't thinks there is anything nothing in the market (yet).